# Images not showing on iPhone device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, image, swift

(Xcode6, Build for iOS7.1, iPhone 4S, Swift)

Images are showing in the simulator, but not on the device. I've been fiddling and hacking away, trying to find the magic formula, but no luck. Here are my efforts to date:

Filename: abc@2x.png, abc.png.
Dragging an imageview onto storyboard and specifying file name via "image" drop-down menu in "Attributes Inspector."
All characters in file names are lower case.

- Dragged and dropped files into images.xcassets folder
- Verified that images.xcassets the "Copy Bundle Resources" section in "Build Settings"

No luck. Deleted files. Re-added using the "+" button at the lower left, and selected "Add files to myProject"

- Checked "Copy items if needed."
- Checked "Create Groups"
- Verified that files were in the "Copy Bundle Resources" section in "Build Settings"

No luck. Deleted files

- Re-added using the "+" button at the lower left, and selected "Add files to myProject"
- Checked "Copy items if needed."
- Selected "Create Folder References" radio button
- Verified that files were in the "Copy Bundle Resources" section in "Build Settings"

No luck. Deleted files

- Went into the GIMP and changed file format to .jpg

  1. Repeated steps above with the .jpg file.
- Dragged new imageview into the view controller, and set the image for this container using the drop-down menu.

Still no luck

- Deleted app from phone several times to allow for a clean install.

Still no luck.

- Project -> "Clean"
- Project -> "Build"
- Restarted Xcode

Still no luck.
Any ideas?

If anyone needs me, just look for the guy banging his head on his desk. :/

Comment: does the image load when loading programmatically? `var image = UIImage(named: "abc")    println(image)`

Comment: It does load; a memory address was printed. I decided to dispense with Storyboard and just use Swift to set the image, and it worked. I will document the answer below.

Comment: I would try using the Xcode images.xcassets folder instead of directly adding the images to the bundle. That said, this might be an Xcode 6 bug. Have you tried adding it to the bundle in Xcode 5 then re-opening the project in Xcode 6?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working, albeit not the way that I wanted it to. I dispensed with the storyboard approach, and just set the background with code.

For posterity:

I. In storyBoard, delete the reference to the `image` in the `Attributes Inspector`. There must be some bug in there. It's not working, and it will break the code below.

II. Create an IBOutlet from the Image View to your controller. You have to do that wire ctrl+drag and hold thing. You should end up with something like this:

```
@IBOutlet var cheese : UIImageView = nil
```

III. In your `viewDidLoad()` routine, set the image programmatically, like so:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.cheese.image = UIImage(named: "cabotClothbound.jpg")
}
```

Of course, you have to make sure that all the stuff in the original question is done: make sure that your case is consistent, be certain that the files are added to your build, etc.

The .jpg file which was dragged n' dropped into the `Images.xcassets` is the one that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your image is taking some other image reference also, Change the image name with any another name then you try with latest one.

```
abc.png to a.png
abc@2x.png to a@2x.png
```

I am sure it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but solved it. The image (in fact, icon) shouldn't be in the Reosurces.bundle, but in the Assets.xcassets.